# sending POST request to express route - after receiving form data, res.render is not triggered

Tags: express, ejs

I'm trying to create a simple app where a picture gets uploaded, and that picture is drawn on html canvas so that i can do some simple pixel manipulation.

Right now I have the GET method for root render an EJS template with a fileReader and a canvas.
With code attached at the bottom of the EJS file through script tags, I draw the uploaded image onto the canvas so I can read each pixel's rgb values.

I then tried to send those rgb values to the POST route in the app (through fetch), but it's not working as expected.

```
app.post("/", (req, res)=>{
    console.log("inside post");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.render("test", {result: req.body});
    console.log("after res.render");
});
```

All three of the console logs print correctly in the terminal, including the request body, but the test template is not being rendered. It just stays on the same "index" view the app launches with.

Can someone give me some insight as to why this is happening? I also included console logs inside the script tags in the ejs template, and these are only displayed in the browser, not in the terminal I launch the express app with. How can I render the view inside the post method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First

If you use AJAX like [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), browser will not render the `test` page.
Because it's asynchronous, and you could see [Ajax in MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX).
You need to use form post with following code.

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
    <button type="submit">go to another page</button>
</form>
```

But, if you use form post, your page which might be "index.ejs" will be replaced with "test.ejs".

In other words,
Browser uses the response from the forms POST request to load the new page.
But browser pass AJAX request's response to a callback and trigger callback in js.
Browser handle these two type request (Form Post and AJAX POST) with different ways.
In common, both are sending data to server.

So, in your case, `res.render` is triggered successfully.
Let me show you an example. Here is my server code.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set("view engine", "ejs")

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.render("test")
})

app.post("/test", (req, res, next) => {
    res.render("other-test")
})

app.listen(3000)
```

```
<!-- test.ejs -->
<h1>this is test pages.</h1>
```

```
<!-- other-test.ejs -->
<h1>this is other test pages.</h1>
```

When I type url http://localhost:300, browser show me this.

[image]

And I open console in chrome and type following code.

```js
fetch("/test", {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: JSON.stringify({}), // data can be `string` or {object}!
}).then(res => {console.log("trigger response")})
```

Then go the network tab in chrome, you will see the request.
Here, this request trigger the express method.

[image]

But, what is the response?

[image]

Well, it's a html. **That means `res.render("other-test")` is triggered correctly.**
And you will find the console output show "trigger response" which callback is triggered in my fetch.
**And, page still stay in "test.ejs".**

Next, I add following code in my test.ejs

```html
<form action="/test" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Go to other page</button>
</form>
```

Page will be like this.

[image]

After you click, you will find out the browser show you "other-test" content.

[image]

That's a difference between form post and ajax post.

### Second

You put script tag into ejs template.
Express will use ejs engine to render your ejs template become to html page.
After it become to html page, it means all script is running in browser not your nodejs terminal.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding - what do you mean it's running in the background so i need to use form post? I'm confused because I've used form post to send data to my express routes, and passing in that data as an argument to res.render() before. 

If I'm using AJAX to send data to hit my express route (and that data can be read within that route), how is it different from the form post method? In both cases aren't I just trying to send data to "app.post('/')" and trying to call res.render with that data passed in?

Comment: I'm mainly explaining why your express doesn't render test.ejs when you use fetch API which is a kind of AJAX to do post. And I mean browser uses the response from the forms POST request to load the new page. But AJAX request's response is passed to a callback in js. Browser handle these two type request (Form Post and AJAX POST) with different ways.

Comment: I understand what you're saying and I appreciate your input, but I still don't understand. I've also tried rendering 'test.ejs' **without** passing in the ajax body in res.render. since the console logs show that i'm clearly hitting the 'app.post("/")' method/route, why is res.render("test") not triggering? 
in `app.post("/", (req,res)=>{res.render("test"});` 
res is the object we need to send desired http response to the client from **express** right? if we're not using the form/ajax data (part of req right?), how does the difference in form/ajax handling stop res.render from working?

Comment: form/ajax both hit your express app, that's right. The important thins is how browser handle form and ajax. You could see my new updated content, I give you an example.